# Present a PDF Document on a Specific Page in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, pdf

I am opening PDF documents using the following ASP.NET code,

```
Response.BufferOutput = true;
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(documentURL);

using (HttpWebResponse responseDDRINT = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream stream = responseDDRINT.GetResponseStream())
    {
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int bytesRead;

        while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) > 0)
        {
            Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        Response.Flush();                        
    }
}
```

My question is does anyone know how to present the PDF starting at a specifice page.  For example, if the PDF document is 15 pages, we would like it to open with page 10 initially showing instead of opening at page 1.

I experimented with the "#page=" open parameter by adding this header, but it did nothing.

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=test.pdf#page=3");
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to manipulate the PDF file on the fly.
Use something like http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/ to stream out a copy of the file starting at a certain page.

Answer (score 0):

1. Current versions of Adobe ready no longer support the page syntax, but they do support the bookmark syntax.
2. Why don't you make your document reachable through a regular link or through an HTTPHandler?

Answer (score 0):

you may use a PDF manipulation library like [ItextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) to get your work done.